# Make temporarySignedRoute expires after it's submitted/opened once

Tags: php, laravel

How to make the temporarily generated route to expire after it is submitted or it can open only one time, even if the expiration time has not reached,

```
    $myRoute = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
      'unsubscribe', now()->addMinutes(30), ['user' => 1]
```

how do I do this?

Comment: you can't update the route after you have already sent it to the user. Instead check if the user in question is already unsubscribed or not.

Comment: let me leave this discussion open, maybe in future someone mighty come up with a solution.